# Is it ok for a construct to return something?

Tags: php, class-design

The case:

I have a form class which handles HTML forms, cleans up fields and validates.

I'm thinking about creating separate classes for the different form fields, e.g.: text / file / select / etc.

The way I'm considering to use this is something like the following:

```
$form = new Form();
$form->element['fieldname'] = new HtmlTextField('length'=>3);
```

However someone here on SO told me once that a class construct should never return anything.

In the above case it would return the form field.

Is it correct that a `__construct()` should never return anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even more so: whatever you return is discarded, and a new instance of the called object is just the return.

Comment: So basically what you are saying (correct me if I'm wrong) is: there is no need to return anything, because what I want is already returned?

Comment: If you want a new instance of `HtmlTextField`: yes, that is already returned, and works fine. Some people swear by factory patterns though, but in most PHP code it isn't strictly needed.

Comment: great. What's the advantage of using factory patterns?

Comment: They may be needed if a context is needed to determine which object to actually create (for instance, a class that extends `HtmlTextField` rather then `HtmlTextField` itself), when some initialisation or dependancy injection is required, when you want to limit a certain object to one instance and all sorts of other things. You might want to check resources on design patterns, for factory patterns, you can get a quick summary & links at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern)

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this.

```
$form = new myForm();
$form->element['fieldname'] = $form->createTextField('length'=>3);
```

myForm will extend the Form Class;

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for a `__construct()` to return anything because PHP returns a new instance of the class after the __construct() is called.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of a class cannot return anything other than an instance of this class when you return something else, this cannot be passed but is discarded.
In your code it seems that this is what you want to have or I misunderstood you.