# Why does this statement returns true when i query the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

#### I know i should be using prepare statements and sanitizing the data i'm just checking the PDO driver

I just want to know why if i'm passing just random data the query returns true?

### just notice this PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object

```php
    $dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';
$formpost = false;
try
{
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=loginexample', $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $formpost = true;
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}

if($dbh && $formpost)
{
    $sql= "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    if($dbh->query($sql))
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to see who'd be the first smartass to comment about this being SQL injection vulnerable.

Comment: It returns true because your query is successful..nothing else

Comment: Oh God both of you are so ***

Comment: @idavid , i did not know, that there is a rude adjective with 3 letters. Also, have you tried [**reading the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) !? Do you know which are the ["truthy values"](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)
?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha i place this in bold to avoid SQL injection comments and you are the first *** that place a comment about it. ##I know i should be using prepare statements and sanitizing the data i'm just checking the PDO driver##

Comment: @idavid: I commented sarcastically, to see who'd be the first to not read that gigantic banner of yours, and comment about it anyway. I think you misunderstood me a little bit :)

Comment: @tereško Have you tried reading this? notice this PDO::query — Executes an SQL statement, returning a result set as a PDOStatement object

Comment: First try if `rowCount()` works with `SELECT` and your database driver: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php - If that does not work, consider to create a `SELECT` query that returns the count your are looking for instead - which might be more appropriate in the first place, too.

Comment: @idavid: You might not know it, but each object in PHP (incl. PDOStatement) evaluates `TRUE` in your `if` condition. http://php.net/boolean - There only is one exception to that rule with `SimpleXMLElement` under *very* certain circumstances.

Comment: Also, [please learn](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) how to prevents SQL injections with PDO. Just because you use PDO does not make your code automagically secure.

Comment: Similar: [Verify method returns true](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9726089/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line: `if($dbh->query($sql))` might not return an object that contains any found records, but it returns an object nonetheless. An object that might tell you that the number of found rows equals zero, for instance.

Try returning true or false based on the number of found records....

Comment: What would you use to fetch those records Fetch_all?

Comment: `$stmt = $db->query($theQueryString); while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){/*do stuff with $row*/}`

Answer (score 3):

`PDO::query` will *always* return a `PDOStatement` object, unless the query caused an error. (Returning no rows is not an error.) In PHP,  any object will evaluate to boolean `true`, so the `if` condition will pass.

Answer (score 3):

Because `PDO::query()` returns a **PDOStatement** object to represent the result set. Even if no results were returned, the query was still successful (i.e. it contained no syntax errors, the table exists, etc).

To check for emptiness, you can use `fetchAll()` and run a `count()` function on that.

Comment: Got it fetchAll and then count();

Comment: Awesome! If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

> PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

My guess is that the query is succesfully getting all zero rows that matched

Comment: Yeah even when doesn't have records returns true, i will chech fetall and then count()>0 to play safe.